# How to show $\frac{dL}{dr}=\int k ds$ (in An isoperimetric estimate for the Ricci Flow on the Two-Sphere)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, ricci-flow

I am reading Hamilton's **An isoperimetric estimate for the Ricci Flow on the Two-Sphere**.  It is   the 9th paper of [Collected papers on Ricci flow](http://library.lol/main/e4b3107a8249e1765db358a82ccc50d8).  For explain my problem, I use the three parts of this paper, which are  the first three pictures below.

I want to know how to show
$$
\frac{dL}{dr}=\int k ds
$$
namely, the first red line. But I feel for general curve $\Lambda$, there should be not the first red line. I  think I should use the characteristic of $\overline\Lambda$ to get the red line. But I don't know how to start.

Besides, I afraid that I misunderstand it. Therefore, I draw a picture in bottom to describe my understand.  Thanks for any help.

**What I try(2023-4-9)**: Consider the unit round sphere
$$
\hat S(\varphi,\theta) = (\cos \varphi\cos\theta, \cos\varphi\sin\theta,\sin\varphi)
$$
where $\varphi\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2], \theta\in [0, 2\pi)$. Let $\gamma(t,s)$ are the curves on $\hat S$,namely
$$
\gamma(t,s)=\hat S(\varphi(t,s),\theta(t,s))
= (\cos \varphi(t,s)\cos\theta(t,s), \cos\varphi(t,s)\sin\theta(t,s),\sin\varphi(t,s))
$$
and $\gamma(0,s)=\gamma(1,s)$ for any $s\in (-\delta,\delta)$. Then I have
$$
|\gamma_t|^2=\varphi_t^2 + \theta_t^2\cos^2\varphi
$$
Let
$$
L(s)=\int_0^1|\gamma_t| dt
$$
So
$$
\frac{dL}{ds}=\int_0^1 \partial_s|\gamma_t| dt
$$
where
$$
\partial_s|\gamma_t|=\frac{1}{|\gamma_t|}[
\varphi_t\varphi_{ts} 
+
\theta_t\theta_{ts}\cos^2\varphi-\varphi_s\theta_t^2\cos\varphi\sin\varphi
] \tag{2}
$$
Since $\langle \hat S_\varphi, \hat S_\theta\rangle =0$ and $|\hat S_\varphi|=1, |\hat S_\theta|=\cos^2\varphi$, the first fundamental form is
$$
I=d\varphi^2 + |\cos\varphi|^2d\theta^2
$$

---

I want to use the geodesic curvature of curve on sphere is
$$
k_g=\frac{d(\gamma_t,\varphi_{curve})}{dt}-\sin \varphi \frac{d\theta}{dt}
\tag{3}
$$
where $(\gamma_t,\varphi_{curve})$ is the angle of $\gamma$ and longitude.

---

In fact, I calculate
$$
(\gamma_t,\varphi_{curve})= \arccos\frac{\varphi_t}{|\gamma_t|}  
$$
As (3), I have (The process is  a little  complicated,  I omit it)
$$
k_g=\frac{
\varphi_t\theta_t\theta_{tt}\cos^2\varphi
-\varphi_t^2\theta_t^2\cos\varphi\sin\varphi
-\varphi_{tt}\theta_t^2\cos^2\varphi 
}{|\gamma_t|^2 |\theta_t \cos\varphi|}
-\theta_t\sin\varphi
\tag{4}
$$
But seemly, it is not equal to $\partial_s|\gamma_t|$.

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: Have you tried to write either a proof or disproof rigorously?

Comment: @Deane  Before you asking me, I don't try to proof. Since Hamilton say "by a standard formula", I've been looking for anything like it in book.  After you asking, I try some calculation. For example, the curves on unit sphere. In fact, I want to use the Liouville's formula. But it need the curves are parametrization by arc length.  I don't know how to deal it. So I found the above (3) which is from Chinese book (微分几何初步).  Although it do not need parametrization by arc length, I  fail to calculate it. And I doubt I am in  right way, since the (4) and (2)  obviously  be not same.

Comment: @Deane  $\gamma(0,s)=\gamma(1,s)$ still not be used. Let me try it again tomorrow.

Comment: Perhaps you know how to prove that the variation of the surface area of a hypersurface is the integral of mean curvature? This is the formula when the dimension of the ambient space is $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation: Given tangent vectors $V,W$, denote $V\cdot W = g(V,W)$ and $|V|^2 =g(V,V)$.

First, there is an ambiguity in the sign of the curvature. The standard definition of the curvature of a curve in a surface is:
$$ \kappa = N\cdot\nabla_TT, $$
where $T$ is the unit tangent vector and $N$ is the unit normal to a curve. On the other hand, the curvature of the curve can be viewed as being the second fundamental form of the curve and therefore the covariant of the normal, i.e.,
$$ \kappa = T\cdot\nabla_TN. $$
These two definitions differ only in sign. Below, I will use the latter, because that appears to be what Hamilton uses.

Now let $\gamma: [0,L] \times (-\delta,\delta) \rightarrow S$, where $\gamma(\cdot,0)$ is the curve $\Lambda_0$ parameterized by arclength and, for each $s \in (0,L)$, $\gamma(s,\cdot)$ is a unit speed geodesic normal to $\Lambda_0$ at $\gamma(s,0)$.

The length of the curve $\gamma(\cdot,r)$ is
$$
L(r) = \int_{s=0}^{s=L} |\partial_s\gamma(s,r)|\,ds,
$$
and therefore
\begin{align*}
\frac{dL}{dr} &= \frac{d}{dr} \int_{s=0}^{s=L} (\partial_s\gamma\cdot\partial_s\gamma)^{1/2}\,ds\\
&= \int_{s=0}^{s=L} \frac{\partial_s\gamma\cdot\nabla_{\partial_r\gamma}\partial_s\gamma}{|\partial_s\gamma|}\,ds\\
&= \int_{s=0}^{s=L} \frac{\partial_s\gamma\cdot\nabla_{\partial_s\gamma}\partial_r\gamma}{|\partial_s\gamma|}\,ds\\
\end{align*}
It follows that if $T(s) = \partial_s\gamma(s,0)$ and $N(s) = \partial_r\gamma(s,0)$, then, since $|T|=|N|=1$,
\begin{align*}
\left.\frac{dL}{dr}\right|_{r=0}
&= \int_{s=0}^{s=L} T\cdot\nabla_TN\,ds\\
&= \int_{s=0}^{s=L} \kappa(s)\,ds.
\end{align*}

Comment: I read it today again, and find Hamilton state that $\frac{dL}{dr}=\int \kappa ds$ for all 
 curve $\gamma (\cdot, r)$, since   he said  $\frac{d^2 L}{dr^2}=\frac{d}{dr}\int k ds$ in follow of his paper.  But this seems to be a mistake.